# Full width slider gallery. Highlighted main image and darker images left and right of the main image

Tags: html, css, slider, gallery

I'm in need of a sliding gallery that spans the width of the page but darks out the other images but highlights the one in the middle on show. Hopefully I explained it enough. I can do a full width slider but I need a full width gallery slider. Thumbnails not so important.

Comment: Please provide a demo of your trials, then ask for help. But to get you started, I suggest slick js carousel with centre mode, and this piece of css: .slick-slide.slick-active:not(.slick-current) {opacity: 0.5};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer using this. using other methords that seem to work for now.

Thanks anyway